# Multi-table insert

Tags: sql, database, oracle, insert

Please guide me whats wrong

```
    SQL> INSERT ALL
      2  WHEN SAL <= 950 THEN INTO scott.e VALUES (E.Empno, E.Ename, E.sal)
      3  WHEN SAL > 950 THEN INTO scott.j VALUES (J.Empno, J.Sal)
      4  SELECT Emp.Empno, Emp.Ename, Emp.Sal FROM scott.emp;
    WHEN SAL > 950 THEN INTO scott.j VALUES (J.Empno, J.Sal)
                                                      *
    ERROR at line 3:
    ORA-00904: "J"."SAL": invalid identifier


   SQL> DESC j
    Name                                                                    Null?           Type
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------- --------  ------------------------------------------------
    EMPNO                                                                            NUMBER(4)
    SAL                                                                              NUMBER(7,2)
```

Kindly requested to provide guideline to rectify code, as best of me code is proper but still generating error. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN SAL <= 950 THEN INTO scott.e VALUES (t.Empno, t.Ename, t.sal)
WHEN SAL > 950 THEN INTO scott.j VALUES (t.Empno, t.Sal)
SELECT Emp.Empno, Emp.Ename, Emp.Sal 
FROM scott.emp t;
```

or just

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN SAL <= 950 THEN INTO scott.e VALUES (Empno, Ename, sal)
WHEN SAL > 950 THEN INTO scott.j VALUES (Empno, Sal)
SELECT Emp.Empno, Emp.Ename, Emp.Sal 
FROM scott.emp ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
INSERT ALL
     WHEN SAL <= 950 THEN 
          INTO scott.e VALUES (Empno, Ename, sal)
     WHEN SAL > 950 THEN 
          INTO scott.j VALUES (Empno, Sal)
     SELECT Empno, Ename, Sal FROM scott.emp;
```

Comment: SQL> INSERT ALL
          2  WHEN SAL <= 950 THEN
          3     INTO scott.e VALUES (Empno, Ename, Sal)
          4  WHEN SAL > 950 THEN
          5     INTO scott.j VALUES (Empno, Sal)
          6  SELECT Empno, Ename, Sal FROM Scott.emp;
                INTO scott.e VALUES (Empno, Ename, Sal)
                   *
        ERROR at line 3:
        ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: @user3134198 `ORA-00913 too many values` error is because of there are more column in tables you are trying to insert.

Comment: @user3134198, try to modify your query like this, `INTO scott.e(empno, ename, sal) VALUES (Empno, Ename, sal)`

Comment: But in Table J there are only two columns and it is giving error for column SAL, Table description is also given above. I don't understand when inserting same number values as the number of columns in table why it is giving an error!

Comment: @user3134198, What about columns in table e?

Comment: It is solved with the INTO scott.e(empno, ename, sal) VALUES (Empno, Ename, sal)  Thanks USER3134198